# How to customize StoreFinderStoreDescriptionComponent in Spartacus?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm want to customize the StoreFinderStoreDescriptionComponent in Spartacus to add another field. Can someone provide an idea how to do that please? Or even how to customize lower level components.

Thanks,

I tried overriding, but doesn't work.